# USB Debugging option greyed out

Tags: android, usb, adb

I have an LG-E405 phone running Android 2.3.6.

I connected my phone with a USB cable and selected the mode as `Charge Only`.

Now when I try to turn on `USB Debugging`, I find that that the option is greyed out.

So, how can I enable USB debugging in this case.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using an Android and is more appropriate for http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is it possible to migrate it there?

Comment: Yes, I have requested a moderator intervene to migrate the question.

Comment: @DanS While this question may be good for android.se, it is not really off-topic here since it pertains directly to needs of a developer for testing/debugging. "software tools commonly used by programmers" from the help center which is linked to close the question.

Comment: If you have 'My Knox' installed, disable or uninstall it and try to activate USB debugging again.

Comment: INDEED this is NOT off-topic. Solving this problem is crucial to getting to the point where one CAN ask a question about programming. See @Gene's Answer below,

Comment: In case you are using Samsung and have MyKnox installed, you cannot enable USB-Debugging until you uninstall MyKnox as stated in [This Link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/note-4/general/usb-debugging-greyed-heres-t3000049)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Finally figured out the solution to the problem, with the help of [this post.](http://androidforums.com/lg-optimus-l3/546049-cant-enable-usb-debugging-permanently-grey.html)

When you connect your phone to your PC, using the USB cable, select the mode as `PC Software`.

Now you should be able to enable USB Debugging.

Comment: Equivalently, go to `Settings -> Connectivity -> Default Mode -> PC Software`. (Worked for me)

Comment: On Usb pc connection->Settings-> install pc drivers worked for me.

Answer (score 366):

You have to enable USB debugging before plugging your device in to the computer. Unplug device then try to enable USB debugging. This should work. If so, you can then plug it back into the computer and it should work

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your suggestion. But still am facing the same problem

Comment: That's strange, that should have worked. My next suggestion would simply be to restart the phone and see if that helps. It's not an AT&T phone by any chance, is it? I only ask because I know that they don't allow third party apps. They have to come from the Google Play store...I learned that the hard way. But I wouldn't think they would do anything with the debugging but you never know

Comment: It's not an AT&T phone. And, restarting the phone did not help.

Comment: I had to put it in PTP mode - crazy stuff :)

Comment: thanks @slott, after hours debugging (or not debugging) i found your comment :)

Comment: For a S7 Edge Disable My Knox =)

Comment: AND, once USB Debugging checkbox is checked, hook up USB cable to computer. Then LOOK for dialog box on device with checkbox indicating that it is OK to debug when linked to the computer. Check it.

Comment: Correct answer.  Key was to unplug from computer.

Comment: thanks @codeMagic. But I am a developer in customized BSP. Once i do Fullpackageupdate, i have to factory reset through adb. But problem is it will disable the USD debugging as soon as it flashed.

Comment: Such a simple solution to a stupid problem. Worked for me! Thanks. It is also worth noting that I had to have my phone in MTP connection mode. I think PTP works as well as @slott mentioned.

Comment: And for the less detail oriented among us (me), this is selecting the actual USB debugging option within developer options, not enabling developer options themselves. :)

Comment: @WilliamT.Mallard this is a good point. This answer was written before they started hiding Dev options.

Answer (score 17):

How to Enable USB Debugging for LG Optimus (LGD415). Android version 4.4.2 (KitKat)
Go to this website and download the drivers to your phone:
http://www.lg.com/us/support/mobile-support
For example, mine would be:
http://www.lg.com/us/support-mobile/lg-LGD415RD. Then click on “Software Update & Drivers”

On your phone, you need to enable USB debugging. To do so,
Go to “Settings”.
Go to “About Phone”
Go to “Software Information”
Tap “Build number” five times.
A pop-up will appear saying “You are now a developer”. Your’re not done yet.

Go back to your phone’s home page by pushing the home button.
Go to “Settings”.
Go to “Developer options”
Click the “USB debugging- Turn on debug mode when USB is connected”. A blue checkmark will appear.

(EDIT: If USB Debugging is greyed out, unplug your phone. USB Debugging should no longer be greyed out. If it is not greyed out, check the box and plug your phone into your PC.)

Unplug your phone from your PC. Then plug it back in. On the pop-up, make sure you set it to “Media Sync (MTP)”.

Now your phone will show up on an option when you want to run your app in Eclipse.

(Look for dialog box on phone and agree to allow debugging connection with your computer.)

(Also, go to Control Panel | Device Manager and make sure there are TWO entries for your phone, similar to those expanded below.)

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Unplug your phone from the PC and go to develop options and now here you can enable USB debugging. if you connect USB and try to enable debugging it will not enable and follow TMacGyver is right it works for me using choose PC connection.

Comment: Yup. For LG X Screen, probably work on similar models, K5 etc

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me:

1. Changing USB connection to File Transfer
2. Turn off developer options
3. Turn it back on
4. USB Debugging option came back to life

Comment: (samsung galaxy a53) Pull down status bar, change `use usb for` from `charging phone only` to `transfering files`, and the `usb debugging` toggle in developer options is available again. Works every time. It seems that this "feature" is implemented deliberately instead of begin a bug.

Answer (score 5):

Unplug your phone from the your computer, then choose PC Software as PC Connection Type.  Then go into Developer Options and select USB Debugging

Answer (score 4):

Just ran into this on the LG Rebel LTE (LGL44VL). As other answers note, you need to change the USB connection mode to PTP. But my phone's control panels were different from stock Android and didn't have such an option.

The option was hiding in a notification that appeared when I plugged the phone in. I had to open the notification tray and tap a notification labeled

> Media Device (MTP)
>   *Tap here for more USB options*

Answer (score 2):

Try selecting the default mode as Internet connection.

Go to **Settings -> Connectivity -> Default Mode -> Internet Connection.**

Now enable the USB Debugging mode under **Applications -> Development -> USB Debugging.**

It worked for me.

Comment: Many solutions I've seen suggest setting the connection to "PC Software", but that was not an option. I tried *everything*, until I set it to Internet Connection (then Ethernet on the next screen) it just wouldn't recognize as a debuggable device.

Answer (score 2):

After countless attempts, I found the following quote:

> If you are using My **KNOX**, you **cannot enable USB debugging** mode while the container is installed. Unfortunately, you have to root your device ...
>   - [continue reading](http://www.syncios.com/android/fix-usb-debugging-grey-out.html#part3)

**Furthermore** make sure:

- your USB-cable works
- your connection type is MTP (or PTP in some cases)
- to enable USB debugging before pluging your device via USB-cable

I switched to another device without KNOX (not rooted as well) to save time. Maybe this quote will save someone some time. It was the only explanation to me in this case.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

FYI My Motorola Xyboard had an "Off" icon at the top of developer options.  Once I tapped that it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Connect the phone to a PC, make sure your developer options are enabled.
Then, connection type must be MTP or File Transfer. Charge only does not allow USB debugging(disables the option).

Answer (score 1):

I had an LG Android phone, and could not get USB to work with Windows, even after trying the following:

1. Settings > About phone > Software info
2. Tap 'Build number' 7x, and Activate Developer mode
3. Settings > Developer options > USB debugging [ON]
4. Settings > Developer options > Select USB Configuration > MTP
5. Plug into Windows PC with USB cable.

It DOES show the phone as charging via USB (so the plug must be OK), but it does not show up under 'This PC' in Windows File Explorer as a Device/Drive.. grrr.

Turns out that not all USB cables are the same — some USB cable manufacturers only make their cable with 2wires instead of 4wires, so that they will charge, but not pass data through the cable — so if software solutions do not appear to be working, try changing the USB cable (!).

im writing this here so that maybe someone else doesnt have to waste half an hour figuring out that some USB cable manufacturer doesnt include all 4 wires in their USB cables... grrr.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that if you have a corporate phone, your corporation IT might also be blocking USB Debugging.  I've tried all the different connection modes and the USB Debugging option remains firmly greyed out.

I'm trying to get in to enable the BATTERY_STATS for GSam Monitor Pro, but I think it's disable through the Airwatch MDM software my company makes me use.  They pay for it so I guess I'm stuck.

Comment: I had this problem with Airwatch installed

Answer (score 0):

To enable USB debbuging you have to enable developer option

1. Go to about device or tablet then
2. Click build number 7 times to enable developer option
3. Now go to developer option scroll down until you see USB debbuging option

Now if you have shaded usb debbuging and it is not turning on

1. Click on the search button on top right corner
2. Search USB
3. Click on USB computer connection
4. Check the MTP

Now you can enjoy your sharing ...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this issue on a current LG phone on a windows computer.  Everything from developer options was enabled correctly, but wasn't able to see the device through ABD.  Needed install drivers which I was able to do from the phone.

After connecting through USB and allowing the connection, I tapped the USB connection type notification and on the screen where you select the type of USB connection (MTP, PTP, etc..) I tapped the three dot icon in the top right hand corner of the screen and selected to install the PC drivers. After installing the drivers on my PC I was able to connect through ABD to debug.