# Can't find Android device to test

Tags: android, usb, device

I'm trying to test an Android application and have a device connected via USB.  The device detects (and charges off) the USB connection but I can't seem to find any record on the computer (running Windows 7) that the device is connected.  I looked in Device Manager and did not see an "Android Devices" category, nor did I see an "Other Devices" category.  I looked on the device manufacturer's website to see if they had drivers; I could not find any.  Does anyone have any idea as to how I could get the device to show on the computer?  Thanks!

Comment: Probably, You may forgot to enable `USB Debugging` on developer option.

Comment: @AxeFox USB Debugging is enabled in the Developer Options panel on the device.  That hasn't changed from when I first got the problem.

Comment: On which port the usb is connected. front port or backport of the CPU ?. Hope you're using PC. If it's in front port, try backport.

Comment: You can check if [any of these answers help you](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14251398/1380752)

Comment: @AxeFox Yes, I am using a Windows PC.  I tried connecting the device to the other USB port and no luck.

Comment: @codeMagic The answers to that question are all about enabling USB Debugging in the developer options.  It is already enabled.

Comment: Yes, but at least one in particular mentions that sometimes you have to have it turned off, unplug from computer, turn on dev option, then plug back in

Comment: did you do `adb devices`? Also you can try killing and restarting adb

Comment: @codeMagic It was worth a try to do that.  Unfortunately, it didn't work.  And yes, I did use adb devices, and I did try killing and restarting adb.  Neither worked.

Comment: @PSDuckie : which device you are using ?

Comment: @codeMagic : **OFFTHETOPIC** I can't join the Android chatroom - room 15 , Could you please add me ? :)

Comment: @AxeFox I'm using a TTX M700DM4.

Comment: @codeMagic i've 1k+ rep. :)

Comment: @codeMagic I completely agree with you about switching to Android Studio.  Unfortunately, for this project, I'm stuck with Eclipse.

Comment: @codeMagic **OFFTOPICAGAIN**. it shows `Only users nominated by the room owner may talk here.`. I think, i got kicked long time ago . :')

Comment: @PSDuckie Have you tried 'Universal ADB Driver' ? http://adbdriver.com/

Comment: @AxeFox I tried to install the Universal ADB Driver but it gave me an "[Error] Device not found".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the USB cable I was using was a charge-only cable.  After switching the cable out, the device showed on ADB.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably windows and especially android adb will see your android device after installing the [Google USB Driver](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html)

I had the same problem for many of my android devices and most of them are running fine with the driver from google. Only for some sony devices I had to install special drivers.

Comment: I have the Google USB driver on my computer but, as I can't see the device on the computer, I have no way to install it.

Comment: In this case I would  reinstall the lastest mainboard/chipset driver in oder to fix potential USB issues

Comment: Are you talking about the drivers on the PC or the Android device?

Comment: The drivers on the PC. The chipset driver does wonders sometimes. If that doesn't help I would connect my android device to another PC to check against.

Comment: Okay, I haven't tried the chipset drivers yet.  However, I did try to connect the device to another computer.  It did not work.

Comment: Update: I tried to connect the device to a third computer - this time a Mac - and it didn't show up on the Mac either.  I'm still extremely confused about why this is happening, and still extremely frustrated that it is still happening.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio go to Tools -> Android -> Android Device Monitor. Once it opens close it, this will reset your adb and you should be able to see your device

Comment: One problem: I'm not using Android Studio.  I'm using Eclipse.  Is there an equivalent command in Eclipse?

Comment: @PSDuckie From command line go to your directory of adb, usually `cd Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools` then run `./adb kill-server` then `./adb start-server`

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't change anything; the device still does not show up on the adb devices.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem sounds related with drivers

the Google USB Driver works only for some android models, some other drivers are installed as plug and play but some others you have to install manually.

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

Also sometimes it happened to me that the adb didn't recognize the device while the screen was locked so you could also check that out.

Comment: I looked at that page, and the OEM for the device I'm using is not listed.  As for the locked-screen issue, the screen has been unlocked during all of this testing.

Comment: That site says the list is not exhaustive, so you could try looking googling the drivers youself and/or tell us your device model so we can check for the drivers.

Comment: Believe me, I have tried to find the drivers, mainly on the manufacturer's website.  But if you want to see if you can find the drivers where I have failed, I'm using a TTX M700DM4.

Comment: if you can, try with a different device to check if it is the drivers or something else

Comment: Okay, I tried with another device (from a different manufacturer) and got the same result.