# Unable to connect LG G6 to ADB

Tags: android, adb, lg

Im struggling with adb and LG G6 on OSX.

1. Tried installing LG Mobile drivers.
2. Tried MPT, PTP and other modes with no luck
3. Tried enabling USB thetering

Nothing seems to work, anyone with the same problem??

Thanks!

Comment: Just in case, the phone is already on developer mode and with adb debug enabled

Answer (score 60, accepted):

As I was looking for an answer, I somehow managed to make it work:

1. Go to Settings
2. Go to Developer options
3. Under *Networking*, tap on Select USB Configuration
4. Select *MIDI device*

Easier alternate would be as soon as you connect the device via USB, just select *MIDI device*. This should initiate the installation of the device.

[image] [image]

Afterwards, it should be visible in your USB device list in Android Studio.

[image]

Comment: Oddly enough my ADB drivers were working, but then stopped (same day), this odd fix solved the problem! Thanks.

Comment: Very useful. I found that the USB mode reverted to MTP every time the device went to sleep, so I had to enable the 'Stay Awake' developer option too.

Answer (score 5):

You need to enable USB Debugging in your LG G6 so adb detects your connected device.

(Just in case you don't know)

To enable USB debugging you need to enable Developer Options in your phone first. To do this:

Go to Settings > About phone > Software info > and then tap the build number about 7 times.

I know that this might sound so obvious but since you did not mention that you have USB Debugging on, I thought that you might have forgotten this step prior to connecting with adb.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make it work you must verify also the USB debugging is enabled. In my case it was disabled and grayed out. 
I found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251398/usb-debugging-option-greyed-out#) I need to connect the USB cable only after taping on 
"Developer options" -> "Debugging" -> USB Debug -> ON.

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

I have met this problem when i was trying to debug an App in LG G6. In my case, I tried all the methods above, such as enable developing and change the connection types and so on, it is still useless. But when I try to remove the built apk file from my computer to the device and try to install it on the device. It failed. So, I decide to open the Applications page in settings, and I found my App is still installed.(I once tried to uninstall the App.) So I re-uninstalled the App and try to connect again, and it works. So, the conclusion is:

Try to find your App in Applications page in setting, maybe your App is still installed but just disabled as me.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

met same problem here. Going through these steps and my debug device(LG G6) pop up in android studio adb device list.

1.make sure usb debugging option is turn on.

2.select usb connection behavior: MIDI (check always connect as MIDI)

3.install LG Universal Mobile Drivers (https://www.lg.com/us/support/software-firmware-drivers)

4.change usb connection behavior: back to MTP (or android studio can not upload apk)

5.start debug in android studio.

Development environment: window 8.1, android studio 3.1.3.