# Debugging option is disabled in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: Debug option is disabled in android studio]

I did Invalidate cache and restart android studio.

Debug option is available for another project But not available for this project. Gradle built succesfully. But why debugging is disabled.

Please help me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try clean and build?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [USB Debugging option greyed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251398/usb-debugging-option-greyed-out)

Comment: yes but not working@ReazMurshed