# How to enable development option on android when it's grey tint?

Tags: android, smartphone, dev-mode

I tried to enable dev mode on my phone, however the button "enable" is in grey tint, how to fix that please ?

[image: screen of my problem]

Answer (score 1):

click on "desactive" first (enable it), then you should be able to access greyed out options

Comment: It's the "desactive" button which is grayed.

Comment: @Nooby is it clickable? Please share your device/os details

Comment: No clickable.
it's an Samsung galaxy A3 2017 with Android 7.0 
And last week it was clickable without problem.

Comment: I would try: 1. restart device 2. tap on build number multiple times to 're-enable' developer mode

Comment: I tried that but it's still don't work. I also tried to remove the cache and the memory of "app->setings" in order to reset the dev mode and the button is still greyed.. Maybe it's because I installed Avast and remove it ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251398/usb-debugging-option-greyed-out). Possible solutions are to unplug the usb and try enabling the developer mode or to select the connectivity mode as pc-software.

Comment: I tried to change the connectivity mode and unplug usb but it's don't work